# When to use Hcatalog and what are its benefits

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm new to Hcatlog (HCAT), we would like to know in what usecases/scenario's we use HCAT, Benefits of making use of HCAT, Is there any Performance Improvement can be gain from HCatlog. Can any one just provide information on when to use Hcatlog

Answer (score 2):

Apache HCatalog is a table and storage management layer for Hadoop that enables users with different data processing tools – Apache Pig, Apache Map/Reduce, and Apache Hive – to more easily read and write data on the grid.

HCatalog creates a table abstraction layer over data stored on an HDFS cluster. This table abstraction layer presents the data in a familiar relational format and makes it easier to read and write data using familiar query language concepts.

HCatalog data structures are defined using Hive's data definition language (DDL) and the Hive metastore stores the HCatalog data structures. Using the command-line interface (CLI), users can create, alter, and drop tables. Tables are organized into databases or are placed in the default database if none are defined for the table. Once tables are created, you can explore the metadata of the tables using commands such as Show Table and Describe Table. 
HCatalog commands are the same as Hive's DDL commands.

HCatalog’s  ensures that users need not worry about where or in what format their data is stored. HCatalog displays data from RCFile format, text files, or sequence files in a tabular view. It also provides REST APIs so that external systems can access these tables’ metadata.

HCatalog opens up the hive metadata to other Map/Reduce tools. Every Map/Reduce tools has its own notion about HDFS data (example Pig sees the HDFS data as set of files, Hive sees it as tables) HCatalog supported Map/Reduce tools do not need to care about where the data is stored, in which format and storage location.

1. It assist integration with other tools and supplies read and write interfaces for Pig, Hive and Map/Reduce.
2. It provide shared schema and data types for Hadoop tools.You do not have to explicitly type the data structures in each program.
3. It Expose the information as Rest Interface for external data access.
4. It also integrates with Sqoop, which is a tool designed to transfer data back and forth between Hadoop and relational databases such as SQL Server and Oracle
5. It provide APIs and webservice wrapper for accessing metadata in hive metastore.
6. HCatalog also exposes a REST interface so that you can create custom tools and applications to interact with Hadoop data structures.

This allows us to use the right tool for the right job. For example, we can load data into Hadoop using HCatalog, perform some ETL on the data using Pig, and then aggregate the data using Hive. After the processing, you could then send the data to your data warehouse housed in SQL Server using Sqoop. You can even automate the process using Oozie.

**How it works:**

1. Pig- HCatLoader and HCatStore interface
2. Map/Reduce- HCatInputFormat and HCatOutputFormat interface
3. Hive- No Interface Necessary. Direct access to metadata

**References:**

[Microsoft Big Data Solution](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/microsoft-big-data/9781118729083/17_chapter-07.html)

http://hortonworks.com/hadoop/hcatalog/

**Answer to your question:**

As I described earlier HCatalog provides shared schema and data types for hadoop tools It simplifies your work during data processing. If you have created a table using HCatalog, you can directly access that hive table through pig or Map/Reduce (you cannot simply access a hive table through pig or Map Reduce).You don't need to create schema for every tool.

If you are working with the shared data that can be used from multiple 
users(some team using Hive, some team using pig, some team using Map/Reduce) then HCatalog will be useful as they just need to table only to access the data for processing.

It is not replacement of any tool It a facility to provide single access to many tools.

Performance depends on your hadoop cluster. You should do some performance benchmarking in your Hadoop cluster to major performance.

Comment: Hi, it looks like you just copied part of this answer verbatim from the "Microsoft Big Data Solutions" book. Could you [edit your post and give attribution to the author](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)? Plagiarism isn't really welcomed on Stack Overflow, and it's always nice to give credit where credit is due. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I have taken some reference from the book and Hortonworks website. I have added it as reference. Thanks for your suggestion.